# Python Flask import list

Tags: python, list, flask, cron

I'm new to python and can't seem to figure it out..

I have following code saved as content.py

```
    import fnmatch
import os
matches = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("Z:\\"):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.iso'):
        matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))

for item in matches:
    print(item)
```

I have following code for website in website.py :

```
    from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('192.168.1.8', 8080)
```

I tried many combinations to get it to work so my matches gets added into the website.py somehow. Can i add a list directly into the website.py? The list will have lines of OS iso copies.

I would like to website.py run every houre as a cron job.

Do i need to stop the website in website.py to refresh it contents inside the cron job?:

```
    @app.route('/shutdown', methods=['POST'])
def shutdown():
    shutdown_server()
    return 'Server shutting down...'
```

Sorry for these questions, but i'm more a scripter.. so using stuff i know but using program languages is very different.

Thanks,
Ward

Comment: Because you need some data to persist, you can either use a database like Sqlite3, or just have your cron dump the results into a json file and read that file on a request. If you're going to get any kind of traffic you'll want to do a database, though, because every time you open the file to read it you will block any other requests from opening the file.

Comment: its just for personal use. So json file would work.

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

content.py

```
    import fnmatch
import os
matches = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("Z:\\"):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.iso'):
        matches.append(os.path.join(filename))

new_list = matches

result_string = """<HTML>
<body>
    <h1>Attendance list</h1>
    <table>\n"""
for i in new_list:
    result_string += "        <tr>\n            "
    for j in i:
        result_string += "<td>%s</td>" %j
    result_string += "\n        </tr>\n"
result_string += """    </table>
</body>
</HTML>"""
display = open("table.html", 'w')
display.write(result_string)
display.close()

##for item in matches:
    ##print(item)
```

website.py

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask('flasksubs')
webcode = open('table.html').read()

@app.route('/')
def webprint():
    return webcode 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host = '10.1.16.14', port = 82)
```